# class methods in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, devise

I'm trying to implement authentication with Devise (an authentication gem for Rails) using Backbone. Users can sign out of Backbone by sending the DELETE request to `/users/sign_out/` so I couldn't get this link to work because if I click it it's a GET request

```
<li><a href="/users/sign_out" class="thumbnail plain">sign out</a></li>
```

I then created a logout method on the User model, but to trigger it I have to have an instance of the user model (obviously). I created a logout method in the router that gets triggered by navigating to the `logout` route, but since I can only call `logout` on the user model with an instance of it, I'm creating a new model in the logout method just to call logout.

```
    "logout": "logout"

    },

    logout: function(){
     var foo = new app.Models.User
     foo.logout();

    }
```

This is obviously a bad idea but I don't know what else to do.  Can you recommend what I should be doing instead? Is there a way to make the logout a class method so I don't have to instantiate a new model just to logout or something else?

Update

This is the createUser method in the User model that sends the registration data to devise. In the success callback, it assigns the session to a variable `window.app.current_user = userSession;`. I also have a logout method on the user model that I try to call from the router like this

logout in router

```
logout: function(){  
    window.app.current_user.logout();
    }
```

--

```
app.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
      initialize:function () {       

    }, 
    createUser: function() {
    var user = {};
    user['email'] = this.get("email");
    user['password'] = this.get("password");
    user['password_confirmation'] = this.get("password_confirmation");
    var registration = {};
    registration['user'] = user; 
  var _this = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/users.json',
    type: "POST",
    data: {user: user, registration: registration},
    success: function(userSession, response) {

      window.app.current_user = userSession;

    },

   ... code ommitted

logout: function(){
  var me;
  console.log("Logging out...");
  me = this;
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/users/sign_out',
    type: "DELETE",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       window.app.current_user = '';

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      return alert("Error logging out: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });

},
```

Answer (score 2):

I am slightly confused why you would want to trigger a logout function when the User model has not already been created. Could you please explain your reasoning behind having this logout function in your router?

Personally, I would have a Session model which listens to the click event of your link. This will then call a logout method which will make the DELETE request.

*UPDATE*

Here is a quick JsFiddle which shows creating a model and attaching it to a global variable:
http://jsfiddle.net/Francium123/eBG3E/2/

```
    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize:function () {       
        this.name = "MyName";
        this.password = "password"
    }, 

    login:function(){
        console.log("login called");
    },

logout: function(){
      console.log("logout called");
    }
});

window.MyModels = window.MyModels || {}; 
window.MyModels.User = new User();

console.log(window.MyModels.User.login());
console.log(window.MyModels.User.logout());
```

Please note that this is just an example, I doubt you would want to store the password in the model!

Additionally you should be able to use Backbone Models fetch(GET), save(POST/PUT), destroy(DELETE) methods instead of writing ajax requests directly in the model. If needs be you can override the models sync method.

Comment: I also have a login method on the user model. The user logs in, but I don't have a session,  If I had a session model with a logout method, then I still need to have an instance of the session available to call logout on, which is similar to the problem with the user model i describe. However I'm sure i'm doing it all wrong so if you can give pointers about how to keep the session going in javascript so that I could call logout on it that'd be very helpful

Comment: @Leahcim: if you have a user that you call `login` on then why not keep a reference to that user somewhere so that you can call `logout` on it?

Comment: @muistooshort so just assign the response from the login to a currentUser variable in the success callback (to the login)? keep that currentUser a global variable?

Comment: When you call login, you should instantiate your user model and make it available throughout your application so you can reference it.

Comment: I do instantiate the user model but don't know how to keep it available throughout the application.

Comment: I use requireJs to modularize my models and just return a singleton. However, you may want to consider having a global namespace convention to store your models. e.g. window.MyModels = window.MyModels || {}; MyModels.User = Backbone.Model.Extend({..});

Comment: I did this  `app.current_user = userSession;` in the success callback to registration, but I when I try to do this   `app.current_user.logout();` in the logout it says can't call logout of undefined

Comment: Could you update your question with the updated code? Essentially once you have logged in you should have your populated userSession model. At this point you can assign your userSession model to a global variable:
window.MyModels.UserSession = userSession;
You should then be able to access this model globally. This approach works for a single page application. However, if you need to load other pages then you will need to store something like a userId / authenticationToken in a cookie or HTML5 storage.

Comment: Added an example to the original answer. It does not do the actual login/logout but shows how the model can be attached to the window object.